# first: and last: , even: and odd: don't work on "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-variants

so I'm learning tailwind CSS but when I arrived at variants I got stuck

so when I use first: and last: only first works and it gets applied to all my list elements, it is supposed to work only to the first one,  its the same for even and odd, please help me out

[image: 1]

```
<ol class=" first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
   </ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This classes should be [applied](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first-last-odd-and-even) on child elements, not parent

```html
<ul class="">
  <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/CT1ddraF7g)

In case you HAVE control over every element it is better to change style on exact element

```html
<ul class="">
  <li class="bg-green-500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="bg-black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>
```

This utility class is very useful when working with loops. For example

```html
<ul class="">
    <!-- Some Loop -->
  @foreach($els as $el)
    <li class="first:bg-green-500 last:bg-black">First will be green, last will be black.</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: but it doesn't make sense if it was like that i'll directly apply backgrounds directly withouts adding first or last , + in the tailwind documentation theye have added the first and last to the parent and it get applayed to the first child and last one ,               
      `<table>
  <!-- ... -->
  <tbody>
    {#each people as person}
      <!-- Use a white background for odd rows, and slate-50 for even rows -->
      <tr class="odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-50">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    {/each}
  </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: it makes perfect sense - it is supposed to be used in loops where you have no control over certain elements

Comment: for exemple if i want to creat a huge table and the color will be different for each row, for exemple the odd must be grey and the even must be white so i have to apply the colors one by one ! i remember in pure css it was not like that you apply it to the parents and the children will have it...

Comment: Just realized placed same link twice, updated answer. The documentation place it on child (not parent) - see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first-last-odd-and-even)

Comment: i think i finally got you, thank you for your time sir you were a big help

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the accepted answer and want to apply it to the parent element instead of all the children, here is another way to do the same in TailwindCSS. Here is the [demo link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Y5cWycoA8A) on tailwind playground.

```html
<ul class="[&>*:last-child]:text-blue-600 [&>*:last-child]:font-bold ">
        <li>First List Item</li>
        <li>Second List Item</li>
        <li>Third List Item</li>
        <li>Fourth List Item</li>
        <li>Fifth List Item</li>
        <li>Last List Item</li>
    </ul>
```